# Replace a column data with another column of data in a data frame while replacing prior instances <0 by 0

Tags: r

I have a data frame

```
x<-c(1,3,0,2,4,5,0,-2,-5,1,0)
y<-c(-1,-2,0,3,4,5,1,8,1,0,2)

data.frame(x,y)
    x  y
1   1 -1
2   3 -2
3   0  0
4   2  3
5   4  4
6   5  5
7   0  1
8  -2  8
9  -5  1
10  1  0
11  0  2
```

I would like to replace the data in column y with data from column x and also replacing in y the instances that where <0 in y and replacing them by 0. This will result in the following data frame

```
data.frame(x,y)
    x  y
1   1  0
2   3  0
3   0  0
4   2  2
5   4  4
6   5  5
7   0  0
8  -2 -2
9  -5 -5
10  1  0
11  0  0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x<-c(1,3,0,2,4,5,0,-2,-5,1,0)
y<-c(-1,-2,0,3,4,5,1,8,1,0,2)
df <- data.frame(x, y)
df$y <- ifelse(y<0,0,x)
df
#     x  y
# 1   1  0
# 2   3  0
# 3   0  0
# 4   2  2
# 5   4  4
# 6   5  5
# 7   0  0
# 8  -2 -2
# 9  -5 -5
# 10  1  1
# 11  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your `x` and `y` vectors, create the `data.frame` in one swift move:

```
> data.frame(x, y=ifelse(y < 0, 0, x))
    x  y
1   1  0
2   3  0
3   0  0
4   2  2
5   4  4
6   5  5
7   0  0
8  -2 -2
9  -5 -5
10  1  1
11  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

In one line:

```
> df <- transform(data.frame(x,y), y = ifelse(y<0,0,x))
> df
    x  y
1   1  0
2   3  0
3   0  0
4   2  2
5   4  4
6   5  5
7   0  0
8  -2 -2
9  -5 -5
10  1  1
11  0  0
```

Note that the resulting data differs from the reference result you provide on record 10. I suspect that this might be because you applied the condition <= 0 rather than < 0? Otherwise the 1 would be carried across from the x field for this record.